# Reuse pre-allocated opencv Mat/Python object for resize

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.6, image-resizing

I am trying to resize an OpenCV image Mat object to a smaller size as show below:

```
small = cv2.resize(big, (small_height, small_width))
```

This works perfectly fine, however, it ends up creating a new small OpenCV Mat object every time this line of code is called.

Therefore, I am trying to find a way in which I can avoid creation of a new small Mat object every time. Does anyone have an idea if it even possible to reuse a preallocated Mat object for resize output?

Comment: Can't you just use the same name for the input and output?

Comment: I don't want to modify the original input image. I was thinking along the lines of creating a static Mat object in the beginning for storing the output of resize and keep reusing it.

Comment: Why not just make a copy of the input image then reuse that? If your input image was named `image` then you can make a copy with `new_image = image.copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `small = cv2.resize(...)`, you can pass the output object by reference: `cv2.resize(big, (w, h), small)`.

I can't say I really understand what happens under the hoods, but I almost certain that the following method can be used for reusing pre-allocated Python object for resize:

```
# Pre-allocate object (assume output format is uint8 BGR):
small = np.zeros((small_height, small_width, 3), np.uint8)

# Pass output ndarray by reference:  
cv2.resize(big, (small_width, small_height), small)
```

Note:
The OpenCV convention is `(width, height)` and not `(height, width)` as in your sample code.

---

### Update:

It's actually simple to check if `cv2.resize` creates a new object, or reuses the existing one.

Here is a simple test that shows that the OpenCV reuses the existing object:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

big = cv2.imread('chelsea.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

small_width, small_height = 160, 90

# Allocate as twice as much rows (allocate small_height*2 rows istead of small_height rows)
small = np.zeros((small_height*2, small_width, 3), np.uint8)

small[:, :, 1] = 255 # Fill small image with green color
small_slice = small[small_height//2:small_height*3//2, :, :] #Get a slice in the expected size of resized output

# Pass small_slice by reference
cv2.resize(big, (small_width, small_height), small_slice)

cv2.imshow('small', small)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

As you can see the green color is preserved from the original object, and the slice is filled by the output of `resize`.